# How to make an application available on the Internet in Wildfly?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I've finished developing a web application on my local machine using `Wildfly 21` application server. As you can suppose, I was running the application on `localhost` while developing it.

Now I want to install `Wildfly` on the final server machine and run my application on it. So, I'd like to know what is the configuration that I need to do in Wildfly to make my application available on the Internet for everyone to access it. Of course, I'm not talking about all possible configuration, but just about the simplest configuration that needs to be done to make the application available on the Internet.

**UPDATE**

I'm aware that we have this configuration in `standalone.xml`:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

but I'm not sure if it's the only thing we have to change in order to make the application available to everyone.

Comment: You should bind it to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` (at least for the public interface) so that it is reachable from outside. After that, just deploy the WAR.

Comment: Just to be sure: binding to this address `(0.0.0.0)` is the default change everyone does to make applications available from outside, right?

Comment: This just tells the server to listen to connections on all network interfaces. Using `127.0.0.1` means only listening for local connections.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.